# What is the name of this list tool in visual studio?

Tags: forms, visual-studio

[image: Example]

This list of stuff, where you can surf through folders.

Comment: The solution explorer?

Comment: I mean, is something like that in basic visual studio toolbox? Solution explorer's not there. I just wanna this kind of list in my own project

Comment: https://www.dotnetperls.com/treeview

Comment: Thanks, thats i wanted.